# What does the --hint option in grub2's search command do?

Tags: grub2

I'm looking at the official GRUB2 docs for the `search` command, as found on http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#index-search

```
Command: search [--file|--label|--fs-uuid] [--set [var]] [--no-floppy] name

Search devices by file (-f, --file), filesystem label (-l, --label),
or filesystem UUID (-u, --fs-uuid).

If the --set option is used, the first device found is set as the
value of environment variable var. The default variable is ‘root’.

The --no-floppy option prevents searching floppy devices, which can be slow.

The ‘search.file’, ‘search.fs_label’, and ‘search.fs_uuid’ commands are aliases
for ‘search --file’, ‘search --label’, and ‘search --fs-uuid’ respectively.
```

In section 5.3 there are many examples along

```
menuentry "FreeBSD" {
      insmod zfs
      search --set=root --label freepool --hint hd0,msdos7
      ...
}
```

It appears the `--hint` option is undocumented other than as an example. What does it do exactly? What is the exact format of the argument?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`--hint` is used to select which partition to select when there are multiple matched partition. By default the 1st matched one is selected.

Suppose there are 2 storage device with label *boot*  as follows

```
hd0,msdos1
hd1,msdos7
```

then the command :

```
search --set=root --label freepool --hint hd1,msdos7
```

will select *hd1,msdos7* instead of hd0,msdos1

Comment: Any idea why there exist separate --hint-efi, --hint-baremetal, etc. options?

Comment: And if `search --fs-uuid` is used, what use is the `--hint`?

Comment: @SaadMalik, UUID does not have to be unique. Filesystem UUIDs work the same way as labels but UUID is usually generated on FS creation.

Answer (score 5):

This is not described in the [GRUB Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html) but there is documentation to be found in GRUB itself (`search --help` on the GRUB shell):

```
--hint
    First try the device HINT.
    If HINT ends in comma, also try subpartitions

--hint-ieee1275
    First try the device HINT if currently running on IEEE1275.
    If HINT ends in comma, also try subpartitions

--hint-bios
    First try the device HINT if currently running on BIOS.
    If HINT ends in comma, also try subpartitions

--hint-baremetal
    First try the device HINT if direct hardware access is supported.
    If HINT ends in comma, also try subpartitions

--hint-efi
    First try the device HINT if currently running on EFI.
    If HINT ends in comma, also try subpartitions

--hint-arc
    First try the device HINT if currently running on ARC.
    If HINT ends in comma, also try subpartitions
```

Now what is the point of "First try device"?

You have to understand that `search` is a potentially slow operation.

Maybe you have 50 drives, each with 100 partitions, and now `search` has to go through all of these ... until it finally finds the UUID you were looking for in the 2356th attempt.

Or maybe you have a very slow device and checking for its UUID causes `search` to be stuck for a while. There's `--no-floppy` to avoid the most common case, I guess - but other devices can also be slow.

With `--hint`, you set a device to check first. Provided the hint was correct, you skip the otherwise potentially lengthy search operation altogether. So this is a speed optimization. (Probably won't be noticable with just one drive, three partitions)

The effect described in [@totti's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126601/30851) of giving preference to a specific device when there are two with the same LABEL or UUID, that should merely be a side effect.

Sure, if you check one device first, a duplicate on another device should not be found. Even so, it would make more sense to not have such duplicates in the first place. As duplicate UUIDs (or LABELs) can be considered a configuration error, and in case the `--hint` turned out to be wrong, it might still return the wrong device.